# Implement TextField Protocol in Custom UITextField class

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, formatter

I'm using `SkyFloatingTextField` framework (which subclasses `UITextField`) for my textfield and I also want to use `AnyFormatKit` formatter for phone number mask. Because It uses `TextInput` delegate, I created a custom class to implement `TextInput` delegate but I'm getting below error.

> Property 'self.textInputDelegates' not initialized at super.init call

```
class customTextField: SkyFloatingLabelTextField, TextInput{
var content: String?

var attributedContent: NSAttributedString?

var textInputDelegates: MulticastDelegate<TextInputDelegate>


override  init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

init(){
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    textInputDelegates.add(delegate: self.inputDelegate as! TextInputDelegate)
}
}
```

https://github.com/luximetr/AnyFormatKit

https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField

Comment: Have you tried making  `var textInputDelegates: MulticastDelegate<TextInputDelegate>` optional?

Comment: Yes. When I do like that It doesn't conform protocol

Comment: What is `MulticastDelegate`? Based on your defining it as `textInputDelegates`, I get the impression it is an array-based object... so it needs to be initialized before it can be used. Something along the lines of `textInputDelegates = MulticastDelegate()`?

Comment: It is a delegate protocol from AnyFormatKit framework. Actually I'm not sure what I need to cast it.

Comment: Just assign an instance to `textInputDelegates`, either directly where the var is declared (`var textInputDelegates = MulticastDelegate<TextInputDelegate>()`) or in your `init` methods (as @DonMag wrote).

Comment: I can't do it like MulticastDelegate<TextInputDelegate>() because It says MulticastDelegate is internal.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can implement delegate methods of a textfield subclass by making use of a supportive class as below.

class TextFieldSupport: NSObject, TextInputDelegate {
    //Supporting class for your textfield delegate

    var tfDelegate: UITextFieldDelegate?
    //MARK: Implement TextInputDelegate Delegate Methods here.

}

class CustomTextField: SkyFloatingLabelTextField {

    //SkyFloatingLabelTextField Subclass
    var content: String?

    var attributedContent: NSAttributedString?

    var textInputDelegates: TextFieldSupport = TextFieldSupport.init()

    override  init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    init(){

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        textInputDelegates.add(delegate: self.inputDelegate as! TextInputDelegate)
    }

    override var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate? {
        didSet {
            textInputDelegates.tfDelegate = delegate
            super.delegate = support
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives  "Type 'CustomTextField' does not conform to protocol 'TextInput'"and  "Value of type 'TextFieldSupport' has no member 'add'" errors.